# Comparing 2 columns in excel using CountIF

Tags: excel

Having difficulty comparing the 2 columns to get the result

```
list 1     List 2

AT.aaa      Yes
SM.aaa      No
CM.aaaa     Yes
DV.aaaa     Sorry
SI.aaaa     NA
AT.bbb      yes
AT.cccc     NA
SM.cccc     Sorry
CM.bbb      No
```

My Motive is to fill this table

```
      Yes   No   Sorry    NA
AT     2     0     0      1
SM     0     1     1      0
DV
CM
SI
```

I am able to find the count of Yes, No. and sorry individually using Countif but am no able  to find the value of those with the other parameter. Can you guys help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the COUNTIFS() formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"*" & $D2 & "*",$B:$B,E$1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, Can you help me understand the formula ?

Comment: COUNTIFS() allows multiple ranges and criteria, it is AND based.  The first  is using wildcards `"*"` both before and after the criteria to find the strings that contain the criteria. This will find anything that has the value in column D in the values of Column A. Then the second is just a straight forward find.

Comment: @VinodK you would put it in E2 and drag across and down.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help , Scott!